# Why talkey won't change its voice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, espeak

I'm trying to change my espeak voice through Talkey, but it does not work.

First, I searched for the portuguese voices available with

```
espeak --voices=pt
```

And I got the following results:

```
Pty Language Age/Gender VoiceName          File          Other Languages
 5  pt-br          M  brazil               pt            (pt 5)
 5  pt-pt          M  portugal             europe/pt-pt  (pt 6)
 7  pt             M  brazil-mbrola-1      mb/mb-br1
 7  pt             M  brazil-mbrola-3      mb/mb-br3
 7  pt             F  brazil-mbrola-4      mb/mb-br4
 7  pt             F  portugal-mbrola-1    mb/mb-pt1
```

Then I followed [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/talkey) example and tried to change for a female voice, so I could notice the difference

```
 tts = talkey.Talkey(                                                                                                                             
     preferred_languages = ['pt'],                                                                                                                
     engine_preference = ['espeak'],                                                                                                              
     espeak = {                                                                                                                                   
         'options':{                                                                                                                              
             'enabled':True,                                                                                                                      
         },                                                                                                                                       

         'languages':{                                                                                                                            
             'pt': {                                                                                                                              
                 'voice': 'brazil-mbrola-4'                                                                                                                
             },                                                                                                                                   
         }                                                                                                                                        
     }                                                                                                                                            
 )
```

I tried changing for both `brazil-mbrola-4` and `mb-br4` but nothing worked. Can someone help me?

Comment: Does `/usr/share/mbrola` exist in the filesystem?

Comment: Hmm, it didn't. I just added it, but the voice still won't change

Comment: Are there are errors logged at stdout? Even when mbrola is manually copied https://askubuntu.com/questions/554747/how-to-install-more-voices-to-espeak still getting errors here `mbrola: FATAL ERROR : cannot find file /usr/share/mbrola/voices/br4 !`, though the audio is output